# Typescript all lodash/fp return types are any

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript-typings

I have installed in a typescript project:

```
"@types/lodash": "4.14.150",
"loadash": "4.17.15",
```

All of data, when processed through `lodash/fp` is returned as `any`

The following code doesn't report any errors:

```
import {prop} from 'lodash/fp';


const data: { id: string } = { id: 'hello' }

// from the above we know that id is a string, but typing it as a number doesn't report any errors
const meh: number  = prop('id')(data)
```

Without adding the type of `number`, I can see that return type is `any`

How can I fix this, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the typescript typings, [the single string argument form of `prop()` is:](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/fp.d.ts#L3038)

```
(path: lodash.PropertyPath): LodashProp8x1;
```

[And `LodashProp8x1` is:](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/fp.d.ts#L3064)

```
interface LodashProp8x1 {
    (object: null | undefined): undefined;
    (object: any): any;
}
```

So `prop('id')` returns a function that either returns `undefined` or `any`.

It appears that the official typings do not support pulling props out in a type safe way with this call signature.

If you use one of the generic forms with two arguments, and it works like you expect:

```
const meh: number = prop('id', data)
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

Or it looks like there's a generic form for the two function syntax, but you'll have to tell the compiler ahead of time the object type you intend to use:

```
const meh: number = prop<typeof data, 'id'>('id')(data)
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```